# How split single multiple categorical column into binary like one hot encoder use spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, one-hot-encoding

My data is like this:

```
+---+---------+
| id|cate_list|
+---+---------+
|  0|  a,b,c,d|
|  1|    b,c,d|
|  2|      a,b|
|  3|        a|
|  4|a,b,c,d,e|
|  5|        e|
+---+---------+
```

What I want is like this:

```
-------------------------
| id|cate_list|a|b|c|d|e|
-------------------------
|  0|  a,b,c,d|1|1|1|1|0|
|  1|    b,c,d|0|1|1|1|0|
|  2|      a,b|1|1|0|0|0|
|  3|        a|1|0|0|0|0|
|  4|a,b,c,d,e|1|1|1|1|1|
|  5|        e|0|0|0|0|1|
-------------------------
```

I used spark ML OneHotEncoder and tried many ways and finally I got this:

```
+---+---------+-------------+-------------+
| id|cate_list|categoryIndex|  categoryVec|
+---+---------+-------------+-------------+
|  0|        a|          0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|
|  0|        b|          1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
|  0|        c|          2.0|(4,[2],[1.0])|
|  0|        d|          3.0|(4,[3],[1.0])|
|  1|        b|          1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
|  1|        c|          2.0|(4,[2],[1.0])|
|  1|        d|          3.0|(4,[3],[1.0])|
|  2|        a|          0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|
|  2|        b|          1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
|  3|        a|          0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|
|  4|        a|          0.0|(4,[0],[1.0])|
|  4|        b|          1.0|(4,[1],[1.0])|
|  4|        c|          2.0|(4,[2],[1.0])|
|  4|        d|          3.0|(4,[3],[1.0])|
|  4|        e|          4.0|    (4,[],[])|
|  5|        e|          4.0|    (4,[],[])|
+---+---------+-------------+-------------+
```

It's not what I need. When I use python it's really simple and almost two lines code could solve this.
Scala is too hard.

My code:

```
val df_split = df.withColumn("cate_list", explode(split($"cate_list", ",")))

val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("cate_list")
  .setOutputCol("categoryIndex")
  .fit(df_split)
val indexed = indexer.transform(df_split)

val encoder = new OneHotEncoder()
  .setInputCol("categoryIndex")
  .setOutputCol("categoryVec")
val encoded = encoder.transform(indexed)
```

Comment: To your notice you can use PySpark to write the same job. Would suggest you to visit Spark website and look for Transformation needed to do this in Apache Spark.

Comment: Please mention me in your comments if you're not able to find the solution.

Comment: If I may ask, why would you want to do that ? You'll eventually need a vector to train with spark-ml ?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I edited it.

Comment: @eliasah Yes, and use xgboost to train a model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive and direct approach for the initial data of the question.

We should have a `udf` that calculates target cell values, expecting `cate_list` value and the taget column name:

```
val cateListContains = udf((cateList: String, item: String) => if (cateList.contains(item)) 1 else 0)
```

We have a sequence of column names to extract:

```
val targetColumns = Seq("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
```

And let's `foldLeft` on the source `DataFrame`:

```
val resultDf = targetColumns.foldLeft(dfSrc) {
  case (df, item) => 
    df.withColumn(item, cateListContains($"cate_list", lit(item)))
}
```

It produces exactly:

```
+---+---------+---+---+---+---+---+
|id |cate_list|a  |b  |c  |d  |e  |
+---+---------+---+---+---+---+---+
|0  |a,b,c,d  |1  |1  |1  |1  |0  |
|1  |b,c,d    |0  |1  |1  |1  |0  |
|2  |a,b      |1  |1  |0  |0  |0  |
|3  |a        |1  |0  |0  |0  |0  |
|4  |a,b,c,d,e|1  |1  |1  |1  |1  |
|5  |e        |0  |0  |0  |0  |1  |
+---+---------+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: It's not good for big data.Too slow.I have to think out a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_contains`, which returns a Boolean, then cast it to `int`.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_contains

val aa = sc.parallelize(Array((0, "a,b,c,d"), (1, "b,c,d"), (2, "a, b"), (3, "a"), (4, "a,b,c,d,e"), (5, "e")))
var df = aa.toDF("id", "cate_list")   // create your data
val categories = Seq("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
categories.foreach {col => 
  df = df.withColumn(col, array_contains(split($"cate_list", ","), col).cast("int"))
}
df.show()
```

the result:

```
+---+---------+---+---+---+---+---+
| id|cate_list|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|
+---+---------+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  a,b,c,d|  1|  1|  1|  1|  0|
|  1|    b,c,d|  0|  1|  1|  1|  0|
|  2|     a, b|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  3|        a|  1|  0|  0|  0|  0|
|  4|a,b,c,d,e|  1|  1|  1|  1|  1|
|  5|        e|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|
+---+---------+---+---+---+---+---+
```